# Turning off time machine

Tags: time-machine

I cannot turn off time machine. I'm using Catalina and a seagate back up drive plus. I have researched this and many sites. They say go to system preferences, time machine, turn off. When I go to system preferences, time machine, I don't get a turn off button. Is it just me? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you have another backup strategy in place. Files without a backup are waiting to be lost.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a checkbox saying "Backup automatically".

Uncheck it.

[image]